# How to block every file type except .exe from uploading

Tags: php

This is all I have.

```
<?php
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "file/exe")
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000000))
{
```

I need to only upload .exe file types, how can I do this? reg ex?(PHP)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should use something like [`finfo_file`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php). As far as I know, `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` can be spoofed by the uploader to anything he wants it to be.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable way to do that as all information that is sent by the client can be tampered with.

I would simply check the file name extension like:

```
if (strncasecmp(substr($_FILES["file"]["name"], -4), '.exe') === 0) {
    // is .exe
}
```

Additionally, you could look for specific [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Just make sure that if you want to deliver that file you’re using a proper MIME media type (e.g. [*application/octet-stream*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.5.1)).

Answer (score 0):

In addition, you can also check MIME type for each file .exe executable files has always application type of mime

pplication/octet-stream, application/x-msdownload, application/exe, application/x-exe, application/dos-exe, vms/exe, application/x-winexe, application/msdos-windows, application/x-msdos-program

Answer (score -1):

```
$_FILES["uploaded_files"]["type"][$i] != "application/octet-stream"
```